# How to clear expired data in cache?

Tags: caching, design-patterns

I implemented an `ExpireLRUCache` class, which will clear the data when it's times out. There are two ways to achieve this.

1. Use a `timer` to clear the expire data
2. Call the `clean` function in `Add` and `Get`

So, which implementation is better?

Answer (score 0):

Do the simplest thing that could possibly work. For example, assuming your cache is a fixed sized, call clean when adding values. Adding values changes the number of cached items, but getting values does not. Also, the idea behind a cache is that getting is done more frequently than adding and you want to minimize the number of times you call clean. Using a timer means threads and complexity. Prove that the simplest implementation won't work before trying something more complicated.

Unless you are writing this as a programming challenge, the best thing to do is use a mature and popular cache that someone has already written. There are many places to go wrong implementing a cache. For instance, I work in Java. If I need a simple cache I use Guava's implementation. I would not attempt to write my own cache.

Lastly, even if you are writing this as a programming challenge, I suggest finding an existing LRU cache algorithm and implementing in code. When that works, you are free to tweak the code to your liking.